# Oracle Exception Detail

Tags: flyway

I'm using Flyway 3.0 within ANT and I would like to know if the stack when an Oracle error occur could be more detailed.

Example: if my migration script contain this statement:

```
DROP TABLE FOO$;
```

And this table doesn't exist, I expect:

```
ORA-00942 : table or view does not exist
```

But I got:

```
Flyway Error: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 4: DROP TABLE FOO$
```

Not optimal for root cause analysis...

Any idea for better verbosity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ant's standard -d switch to reveal more info. If you feel the standard info should be improved, please file a bug report in the issue tracker.

Comment: Improvement request created on the issue tracker https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/770

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `-X` option to the flyway command line will print debug output.